# Is it possible to wrap a form_widget with a form_label in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

To integrate this in Twig:

```
<label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
    <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.firstname) }}</span>
</div>
```

I used the following code snippet:

```
{{ form_label(form.firstname, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
<div class="controls">
    {{ form_widget(form.firstname) }}
    <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.firstname) }}</span>
</div>
```

And everything worked fine.

**But my question is ...**

**Is it possible to wrap a form_widget with a form_label in Twig?** The final result should then be **similar** to:

```
<label class="radio" for="dn">
    <input type="radio" id="dn" name="spotlight" value="1"> Test 1
</label>
<label class="radio" for="gn">
    <input type="radio" id="gn" name="spotlight" value="1"> Test 2
</label>
<span class="help-block">Errors</span>
```

Can I use anything else than `form_label` and `form_widget` to achive the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the display of the `form_row()` output in only one file:

```twig
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block form_row %}
    <div class="form_row">
        {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
            {% if not compound %}
                {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if required %}
                {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if label is empty %}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {% endif %}
            <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
        {% endif %}

        {{ form_widget(form) }}

        {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
            </label>
        {% endif %}

        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}
```

And display your field:

```twig
{{ form_row(form.firstname) }}
```

The `<label>` is now opening before the field and closing after the field.

I took the original code from [default theme](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L249) and use the [cookbook entry *Form Theming in Twig > Method 1: Inside the same Template as the Form*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form).

If you want to apply your idea to all of your fields, consider using [form customization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#customizing-the-form-row) in order to change the display of `{{ form_row(....) }}` in all your bundle.